# how to make separate module in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

could you please how to make separate module in angular 2 ?I make a simple example of angular in which user on button click show `second page`. But now I want to move my code in separate `module` in angular where I will write  separate`routing` and **components**

I try like this
https://plnkr.co/edit/Vm4OXXCCqCI0uTvGdORn?p=preview

I make separate **module and routing file**

```
const routes =[

      {
        path: 'sd',
        component: Second
      },
      {
        path: '**', redirectTo: ''
      }

    ]
```

**module file**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [ Second],
})
export class SecondModule {}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i am not able to separate my code

Comment: I want to create a `module` with a name of `secondModule` using ngmodule ..and import in app module..In secondmodule I want to show `second page` or second page text

Comment: currently I just create two components..On click I show second component. but second component is not included in any module .so for second component I want to create a module